# Golang wrap query execution in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, go

I am using the following code to wrap execution of aquery on a postgres database in a API I am building just to learn Go.

```
func QueryDB(qstring string) (*sql.Rows) {
    psqlInfo := fmt.Sprintf("host=%s port=%d user=%s dbname=%s sslmode=disable", host, port, user, dbname)
    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", psqlInfo)
    if err != nil {
      panic(err)
    }
    defer db.Close()

    //Ping method opens the connection
    err = db.Ping()
    if err != nil {
       panic(err)
    }

    //rows, err := db.Query("SELECT name FROM users WHERE age = $1", age)
    log.Printf("executing SQL %s\n",qstring)
    rows, err := db.Query(qstring)
    if err != nil {
       log.Fatal(err)
    }
    return rows
}
```

my question is as per the documentation the db.Query() method accepts a query strgin and ...interface{} arguments otherwise. tried adding a second argument 
params ...interface{} to my function arguments and passing params as the second argument to the DB.Query method, and this doesn't work. it only seems to work if I specifically pull the arguments out of the interface slice.
Any suggestions?

Comment: It's a variadic function: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Passing_arguments_to_..._parameters

Comment: BTW, `sql.Open` is meant to open and maintain a connection pool to the database. You will want to `Open` it once, and reuse the handle it returns. The library itself will maintain the base connection and spin up/down any necessary additional connections.

Comment: Since you say you are learning Go, I'll add this as well. "Don't Panic!" is one of the Go mottos. In Go, you **handle** errors on the spot, or return them to the caller to handle. If your code ends up as a library some day and it panics, it terminates someone's program. Generally it is OK to Panic in your own `Main` function if something like a one-off `sql.Open` fails because that __is__ something you would want to terminate your own program. It's something your application simply cannot function without.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://gobyexample.com/variadic-functions) may help you

> Variadic functions can be called in the usual way with individual arguments.
>   If you already have multiple args in a slice, apply them to a variadic function using `func(slice...)`

If you want send `data` from an slice, just add elipsis:

```
rows, err := db.Query(qstring, data...)
if err != nil {
   log.Fatal(err)
}
```

If you has the values separated in different variables:

```
rows, err := db.Query(qstring, val1, val2, val3, valN)
if err != nil {
   log.Fatal(err)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out by lookingin the source code of the SQL module and seeing how it was implemented in the db.Query() method.
you add the elipsis to the end of the slice argument to pass it through. Like params...

Comment: Peek into the standard libraries often and you will learn much.